# Retrieve value of slider

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

I am trying after reading manual get slider working. It returns Null. What I am doing wrong? How do I get current value form slider?

```
$('#slider-fill').slider();
var value = $('#slider-fill').slider("option", "value");

$(document).on('vclick', '#test', function(){    
  alert(value);
});
```

```
<input name="slider" id="slider-fill" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-highlight="true" type="range">

<a href="" id="test">sdfsdf</a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smatisen/eupjvf2x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use jQuery `.val()` -- which gets the value of an input.

```
alert($('#slider-fill').val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/eupjvf2x/2/

You shouldn't need the value var at all, I don't think.

Comment: Man, I was sure it shouldnt work. I checked. Seems that the problem the work at night. :/